# Adding option values and inner HTML from an Array or Object

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the best approach to use JavaScript to create a new HTML element `<option>` from each item in an array (or perhaps not use an array if there's a better method?

How would I run a loop that creates a new `option` for each item in the array and then assign the url as the options value.

[Here is my current JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pt44ffsy/)

My JS is as follows:

```
    var images = [
  "Sports 1",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/1",
  "Sports 2",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/2",
  "Sports 3",
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/3",
];

var index, len;
for (index = 0, len = images.length; index < len; index++) {
    var newoption = document.createElement('option');
    newoption.innerHTML = images[index];
    document.getElementById('imagelist').appendChild(newoption);
}
```

The html should look like this:

```
<form id="imageform">
  <select id="imagelist" name="imagelist">
    <option value="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/1">Sports 1</option>
    <option value="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/1">Sports 1</option>
    <option value="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/1">Sports 1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an object to store your key-value pairs.

```
var images = {
  "Sports 1" :
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/1",
  "Sports 2":
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/2",
  "Sports 3":
    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/3",
};

var index, len;
var keys  = Object.keys(images);

for (index = 0, len = keys.length; index < len; index++) {
    var temp = keys[index];
    var newoption = new Option(temp, images[temp]);
    document.getElementById('imagelist').add(newoption);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Luyxqu75/2/

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of `array`, you should have `array` of `objects`

Try this:

```js
var images = [{
  "key": "Sports 1",
  "value": "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/1"
}, {
  "key": "Sports 2",
  "value": "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/sports/2"
}];

for (var index = 0, len = images.length; index < len; index++) {
  var newoption = document.createElement('option');
  newoption.value = images[index].value;
  newoption.innerHTML = images[index].key;
  document.getElementById('imagelist').appendChild(newoption);
}
```

```html
<form id="imageform">
  <select id="imagelist" name="imagelist">
  </select>
</form>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pt44ffsy/1/)